# Ember.js is it possible to assign any value to transition object's data attribute?

Tags: javascript, ember.js

When performing a transition from a route with `transitionTo` method, I'd like to set it's data object some value? Is this possible somehow?

When entering the target route if I log `transition` object in my model hook, I can see that transition object has an empty attribute like this: `data: {}`.

What is this object for if not to be used to transmit some data in it?

**Update**

Thanks to @Ben's answer I achieved my purpose in this way:

`this.transitionTo('route.name').data = {my: 'data'}`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I definitely use that regularly. Ember doesn't have it documented, although Ember's documentation doesn't really document the transition object as far as I recall. But it comes from `router.js`, and in `router.js` it is [documented](https://github.com/tildeio/router.js/blob/55a4d59c237e330f01afec57872f510e4be5851e/lib/router/transition.js#L135-L145) as a public attribute for exactly the purpose you describe.